# How to calculate the next partial table in Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

When I try to understand KMP by myself, I get some puzzles. I had referenced many online resources and textbooks, but my puzzle still exist, please help me out. You can get some background info about this algorithm from [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/kmpen.htm).

The first case is easy:

[image]

While the second case is hard to understand:

[image]

**My Question:**

1) How to understand, find the proper k' in the second case, is a pattern matching itself process(which means p[1..j] match p[1..x]) ? It looks like matching itself, but not exactly as usual text and pattern match.

2) Why the first element choose to compare with P[j] in second case is P[next[k]],not someone else ? If they match, then why next[j+1] = next[k]+1 ?

3) If the first P[next[k]] not equal P[j] , then why we have to choose the next element P[next[next[k]] to compare with P[j] and continue this process until we find the proper k' or we can not find ? This is a recursive process, how to understand it?

Comment: You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTJr8OvyEVQ) video to learn about KMP.